# ¿Cómo hacer que un select tenga el valor principal antes de editar Laravel?

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel

Estoy usando un select con datos de mi base de datos, mi problema es que el select es para editar un registro de mi tabla de la base de datos... quisiera que el select al presionar editar aparezca el valor a editar y luego los valores posibles para editar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que el campo no apareciera en blanco... si no que aparezca el valor que editaré en un futuro con el mismo select

este es mi div:

```
<div class="form-group row col-xs-4 col-md-4" >
<label class="control-label col-md-4" >Rif Holding: </label>
<div class="col-md-8">
 <select name="holdings_id" id="holdings_id" class="form-control">
    @foreach ($holdings as $holding)
      <option value="{{ $holding->holdings_id }}" class="form-control">{{ $holding->hrif }}</option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
</div>
```

Gracias de antemano..

Comment: Tienes el valor de la opción que debe quedar seleccionada en una variable?

Comment: holdings_id es el valor que quiero que quede seleccionado antes de cambiar... es una llave foranea que hace relación con otra tabla

Comment: Podrías poner un `@if` al ir creando los options, para que si coincide el valor del option con el que tú quieres, se agregue el atributo `selected` al option en cuestión. Algo así `<option value="{{ $holding->holdings_id }}" @if( $holding->holdings_id ===  $holdings_id ) selected @endif   >{{ $holding->hrif }}</option>`

Comment: me ha dado este error ErrorException
Undefined offset: 1 creo que es por esta variable que colocas $holdings_id.. la borré y no me da el error pero sigo con el problema

Comment: No entendí de donde obtienes el valor que quieres que quede seleccionado... Reemplaza `$holdings_id` por ese valor y debería funcionar.

Comment: tienes razon!! muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías poner un `@if` al ir creando los options, para que si coincide el valor del option con el que tú quieres, se agregue el atributo `selected` al option en cuestión. Algo así:

```
<option value="{{ $holding->holdings_id }}" @if( $holding->holdings_id === $holdings_id ) selected @endif >{{ $holding->hrif }}</option>
```

Reemplazando `$holdings_id` por el valor que quieres que quede seleccionado..

Answer (score 0):

Y si pones

solo agregale un **option** arriba del foreach y listo

```
<select name="holdings_id" id="holdings_id" class="form-control">
<option value="" class="form-control">Seleccionar</option>
    @foreach ($holdings as $holding)
      <option value="{{ $holding->holdings_id }}" class="form-control">{{ $holding->hrif }}</option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu respuesta

Comment: si amigo... pero no quiero que me diga seleccionar... quiero que me aparezca el campo que editaré con el select

Comment: No, no es la solución, por favor lee bien la pregunta para que entiendas su problema.